# Total server memory - what is the most accurate way to get it through SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, memory, memory-management, sql-server-2005, dmv

How is it that the values of these 2 queries disagree between each other:

```
SELECT [server memory] = physical_memory_in_bytes /1024.00/1024.00/1024.00
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info;

SELECT object_name, cntr_value 
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE counter_name = 'Total Server Memory (KB)';
```

they should both be showing the total server memory.

Why do they disagree?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe the first shows system memory (give or take a few bytes and rounding errors), the second shows the amount of memory allocated to/used by the actual MSSQL instance.

Comment: @Phylogenesis it makes sense, it seems to be exactly that. do you have any reference for this?

Comment: This [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190924.aspx) gives some information about the performance counters.

Comment: Just a heads up. You attempted to sanitize your system name and the full computer name. But the computer name is still legible and the domain wasn't sanitized (below the full computer name) so anyone can figure out the full computer name. Just thought you would want to know since you seemed like you wanted it sanitized.

Comment: @scsimon this has been sorted now, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physical memory is the total RAM on that server has

You can compare how much memory is SQL Server service is consuming using:
sys.dm_os_sys_info system view committed_kb field and
sys.dm_os_performance_counters view cntr_value

[image]

Comment: Good answer right straight to answer